# Suspend problem with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, suspend

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 on my PC, and the system suspend doesn't seem to work. I've been browsing forums for answers, as this appears to be a common problem, but I can't find an obvious problem that marries up to any of the solutions.

Specifically, when running `systemctl suspend`, the system appears to go to sleep correctly, but then immediately wakes back up. When looking through the `dmesg` logs, there are no obvious errors, and `systemctl status suspend.target` seems to confirm this:

```
○ suspend.target - Suspend
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/suspend.target; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:systemd.special(7)

May 17 09:42:37 systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
May 17 09:42:37 systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
```

The following is the output of `dmesg` after `systemctl suspend`:

```
[ 4077.436687] PM: suspend entry (deep)
[ 4077.446548] Filesystems sync: 0.009 seconds
[ 4077.572957] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[ 4077.574776] OOM killer disabled.
[ 4077.574777] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[ 4077.575932] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[ 4077.576759] serial 00:04: disabled
[ 4077.576851] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Down
[ 4077.712510] [drm] free PSP TMR buffer
[ 4077.822253] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0: amdgpu: MODE1 reset
[ 4077.822257] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0: amdgpu: GPU mode1 reset
[ 4077.822403] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0: amdgpu: GPU smu mode1 reset
[ 4078.418257] ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[ 4078.754702] ACPI: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[ 4078.754804] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[ 4078.756772] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[ 4078.759487] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[ 4078.762431] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[ 4078.764663] smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
[ 4078.766895] smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
[ 4078.769094] smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
[ 4078.769686] Spectre V2 : Update user space SMT mitigation: STIBP off
[ 4078.771213] smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
[ 4078.773289] smpboot: CPU 8 is now offline
[ 4078.775313] smpboot: CPU 9 is now offline
[ 4078.777171] smpboot: CPU 10 is now offline
[ 4078.779119] smpboot: CPU 11 is now offline
[ 4078.779899] ACPI: PM: Low-level resume complete
[ 4078.779921] ACPI: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[ 4078.780115] LVT offset 0 assigned for vector 0x400
[ 4078.780680] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[ 4078.780716] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[ 4078.780716] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[ 4078.780826] microcode: CPU1: patch_level=0x0a20120a
[ 4078.783530] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C002: Found 2 idle states
[ 4078.786823] CPU1 is up
[ 4078.786840] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
[ 4078.786968] microcode: CPU2: patch_level=0x0a20120a
[ 4078.789112] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C004: Found 2 idle states
[ 4078.790796] CPU2 is up
[ 4078.790814] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
[ 4078.790909] microcode: CPU3: patch_level=0x0a20120a
[ 4078.793061] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C006: Found 2 idle states
[ 4078.794806] CPU3 is up
[ 4078.794822] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x8
[ 4078.794917] microcode: CPU4: patch_level=0x0a20120a
[ 4078.797071] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C008: Found 2 idle states
[ 4078.798875] CPU4 is up
[ 4078.798890] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0xa
[ 4078.799007] microcode: CPU5: patch_level=0x0a20120a
[ 4078.801163] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00A: Found 2 idle states
[ 4078.802851] CPU5 is up
[ 4078.802866] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0x1
[ 4078.802994] microcode: CPU6: patch_level=0x0a20120a
[ 4078.805156] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C001: Found 2 idle states
[ 4078.806904] Spectre V2 : Update user space SMT mitigation: STIBP always-on
[ 4078.806918] CPU6 is up
[ 4078.806940] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0x3
[ 4078.807039] microcode: CPU7: patch_level=0x0a20120a
[ 4078.809200] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C003: Found 2 idle states
[ 4078.810937] CPU7 is up
[ 4078.810953] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 8 APIC 0x5
[ 4078.811070] microcode: CPU8: patch_level=0x0a20120a
[ 4078.813227] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C005: Found 2 idle states
[ 4078.814946] CPU8 is up
[ 4078.814961] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 9 APIC 0x7
[ 4078.815062] microcode: CPU9: patch_level=0x0a20120a
[ 4078.817220] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C007: Found 2 idle states
[ 4078.818977] CPU9 is up
[ 4078.818992] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 10 APIC 0x9
[ 4078.819095] microcode: CPU10: patch_level=0x0a20120a
[ 4078.821252] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C009: Found 2 idle states
[ 4078.823000] CPU10 is up
[ 4078.823016] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 11 APIC 0xb
[ 4078.823140] microcode: CPU11: patch_level=0x0a20120a
[ 4078.825297] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00B: Found 2 idle states
[ 4078.827033] CPU11 is up
[ 4078.827967] ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[ 4078.840112] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: xHC error in resume, USBSTS 0x401, Reinit
[ 4078.840115] usb usb1: root hub lost power or was reset
[ 4078.840116] usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
[ 4078.840693] [drm] PCIE GART of 512M enabled (table at 0x0000008000300000).
[ 4078.840728] [drm] PSP is resuming...
[ 4078.840779] serial 00:04: activated
[ 4078.897675] nvme nvme0: Shutdown timeout set to 10 seconds
[ 4078.899643] nvme nvme0: 32/0/0 default/read/poll queues
[ 4078.923848] [drm] reserve 0xa00000 from 0x81fe200000 for PSP TMR
[ 4079.014729] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Down
[ 4079.019015] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0: amdgpu: RAS: optional ras ta ucode is not available
[ 4079.036388] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0: amdgpu: SECUREDISPLAY: securedisplay ta ucode is not available
[ 4079.036390] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resuming...
[ 4079.036392] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0: amdgpu: smu driver if version = 0x0000000f, smu fw if version = 0x00000013, smu fw program = 0, version = 0x003b2900 (59.41.0)
[ 4079.036395] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0: amdgpu: SMU driver if version not matched
[ 4079.036443] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0: amdgpu: use vbios provided pptable
[ 4079.090189] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resumed successfully!
[ 4079.091461] [drm] DMUB hardware initialized: version=0x02020013
[ 4079.153056] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 330)
[ 4079.153077] ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[ 4079.153131] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 330)
[ 4079.156814] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 330)
[ 4079.258843] usb 1-1: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 4079.291036] [drm] kiq ring mec 2 pipe 1 q 0
[ 4079.295257] [drm] VCN decode and encode initialized successfully(under DPG Mode).
[ 4079.295626] [drm] JPEG decode initialized successfully.
[ 4079.295644] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx_0.0.0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 0
[ 4079.295645] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.0 uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 0
[ 4079.295645] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 0
[ 4079.295646] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.0 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 0
[ 4079.295646] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.0 uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 0
[ 4079.295647] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.1 uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 0
[ 4079.295647] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.1 uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 0
[ 4079.295647] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.1 uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 0
[ 4079.295648] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.1 uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 0
[ 4079.295648] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0: amdgpu: ring kiq_2.1.0 uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 0
[ 4079.295649] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0: amdgpu: ring sdma0 uses VM inv eng 12 on hub 0
[ 4079.295649] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0: amdgpu: ring sdma1 uses VM inv eng 13 on hub 0
[ 4079.295650] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_dec_0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 1
[ 4079.295650] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc_0.0 uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 1
[ 4079.295651] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc_0.1 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 1
[ 4079.295651] amdgpu 0000:08:00.0: amdgpu: ring jpeg_dec uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 1
```

I've checked all the obvious stuff I know about, I have more `swap` than I do RAM, my BIOS settings don't have anything on the power management side that clearly blocks sleep/suspend, I'm using the AMD driver packaged with Ubuntu, no proprietary drivers for any peripheral devices.

This is a PC, custom build: 32 GB RAM (34 GB Swap), AMD Radeon RX6600, AMD® Ryzen 5 5600X, Gigabyte B550M Motherboard.

[image: System About]

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To make it easier to troubleshoot, and for future members who might have the same issue you describe here, can you please add your computer (a laptop?) make/model to the question? Thanks

Comment: Maybe these links could help you find a workaround: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=233668 and https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#Instantaneous_wakeups_from_suspend and https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Archiv/pm-utils/

Comment: @Gauss have you had any luck debugging this?

Answer (score 2):

Here from googling for the fix after a reinstall and finding this ask live this round.

This is likely the "Gigabyte B550 family boards do not come out of suspend on linux" GPP0/GPP8 bug that seems to happen with NVME SSDs.  It was impossible for me to diagnose, with every error turning out to be a red herring, until someone saw my logs who had seen it before.  I'd be unable to come out of suspend, and could only wake up by rolling the dice and cycling the rear switch off and on before the memory lost charge (or whatever process does that).

from the Reddit post https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/11urtla/comment/jg46a0p:

> The GPP bridge is causing the issue, probably when an nvme ssd is installed. Disabling wakeups from the bridge fixes the issue.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=284401 is the initial fix,

```
$ sudo sh -c "echo GPP0 > /proc/acpi/wakeup"
$ sudo sh -c "echo GPP8 > /proc/acpi/wakeup"
```

https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/11urtla/comment/jg46a0p adds a systemd service that changes it every time on boot:

> It would also make sense to create a systemd service to do this on each boot. Create a file named /etc/systemd/system/sleep-workaround.service with this content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Workaround for Gigabyte B550 AC bios sleep bug

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo GPP0 > /proc/acpi/wakeup && echo GPP8 > /proc/acpi/wakeup"

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

> And then enable the service with [sudo systemctl daemon-reload and] sudo systemctl enable sleep-workaround. I hope this information eventually helps someone.

Posting here even if it's laid fallow for 6 months, hoping it catches someone googling.  This is a bear to debug if you don't know what you're looking for.

Since DMs aren't enabled here, would someone with commenting reputation please reply to the thread above and alert @scrollout to this? their question got closed but it's the same question.

Comment: Exactly what I needed for my Gigabyte B550M--this one has been driving me crazy! THANK YOU!

Comment: yeah.  sometimes system updates break it for me and I have to re-enable it in systemd, but it's a small price to pay for being able to stop googling every time it happens :).

Comment: there's a chance that if this doesn't work, your problem is actually with AMD Freesync monitors and related things, disabling display power saving (shutting off the display before suspending) will fix it, unfortunately it does mean your monitor no longer sleeps unless your computer does.

I never bothered to find a workaround.