# Ubuntu 22.04.3 won't wake up after suspending

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, suspend, wakeup

I know this question has been asked before, but the questions and answered have addressed previous versions of Ubuntu, and NVIDIA drivers, and haven't worked for me, so I am creating a new question.

How can I get Ubuntu to sleep properly?

My computer is comprised of,

- GPU: Nvidia 4060 TI
- Driver: 535.129.03 (I've also tried metapackage and driver variants, 525, and X.Org X server Nouveau [on top of suspend issues, this also scales the entire display])
- CUDA Version: 12.2
- CPU: AMD 5700X
- Board: Gigabyte 550 Gaming V2 rev 1.3, BIOS `FDc`
- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Basically, when I select `suspend` on Ubuntu, my screens turn off, my mouse light turns off, and my fans spin up to a very high RPM. I can doubled click, and my mouse light will turn on again, but the screens stay black, and I am unable to wake it up from this state. In order to wake it, I need to toggle the PSU switch off, and then back on. After that, the login screen is displayed (I would've thought cutting the power for 2 seconds would turned the computer completely off?).

Anyway, **I know this is an Ubuntu related issue because I can put my computer to sleep on Windows 10, and wake it back up again.**

What I've tried so far to get suspend to work is listed here,

- Editing `/etc/defaults/grub` (GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.blacklist=1")
- Removing all NVIDIA services in `/etc/systemd` (https://askubuntu.com/a/1409631/1554429)
- Installing different Nvidia drivers, both open source and proprietary options
- Setting the Nvidia sleep shell script to only execute `exit 0`
- Disabled secure boot in BIOS
- Disabled CSM in BIOS
- Enabled mouse and key presses to wake in BIOS
- Disabling Nvidia systemd state management (https://askubuntu.com/a/1436923/1554429)
- Updating the BIOS

Here is a log dump spanning the suspend command, screens going dark and fans spinning fast and loudly, then a double click to try and wake the computer, a toggle of the of power switch on my PSU, then logging in again. It seems like the CPUs go to sleep, but then wake up immediately after.

```
...
Nov 14 23:35:16 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) event5  - Razer Razer DeathAdder V2: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.
Nov 14 23:35:25 COMPUTER systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER systemd-logind[1205]: Delay lock is active (UID 1000/USER, PID 2628/gnome-shell) but inhibitor timeout is reached.
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system suspend actions...
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER suspend[21829]: nvidia-suspend.service
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER logger[21829]: <13>Nov 14 23:35:45 suspend: nvidia-suspend.service
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (**) Option "fd" "40"
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (**) Option "fd" "43"
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) event0  - Power Button: device removed
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (**) Option "fd" "44"
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) event2  - Logitech USB Keyboard: device removed
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER systemd[1]: Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (**) Option "fd" "45"
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) event3  - Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control: device removed
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (**) Option "fd" "46"
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) event4  - Logitech USB Keyboard System Control: device removed
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (**) Option "fd" "47"
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) event5  - Razer Razer DeathAdder V2: device removed
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (**) Option "fd" "48"
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (**) Option "fd" "49"
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) event8  - Razer Razer DeathAdder V2: device removed
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (**) Option "fd" "48"
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) event6  - Razer Razer DeathAdder V2 Keyboard: device removed
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER systemd[1]: grub-initrd-fallback.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 14 23:35:45 COMPUTER systemd[1]: Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
Nov 14 23:35:46 COMPUTER kernel: rfkill: input handler enabled
Nov 14 23:35:46 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:69
Nov 14 23:35:46 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:68
Nov 14 23:35:46 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:65
Nov 14 23:35:46 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:67
Nov 14 23:35:46 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:72
Nov 14 23:35:46 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:64
Nov 14 23:35:46 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:70
Nov 14 23:35:46 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:66
Nov 14 23:35:47 COMPUTER systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 14 23:35:47 COMPUTER systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system suspend actions.
Nov 14 23:35:47 COMPUTER systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Nov 14 23:35:47 COMPUTER systemd-sleep[21845]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Nov 14 23:35:47 COMPUTER kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.144 seconds
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: Freezing user space processes
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: Freezing user space processes completed (elapsed 0.002 seconds)
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: OOM killer disabled.
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks completed (elapsed 0.001 seconds)
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ACPI: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: CPU 8 is now offline
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: Spectre V2 : Update user space SMT mitigation: STIBP off
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: CPU 9 is now offline
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: CPU 10 is now offline
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: CPU 11 is now offline
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: CPU 12 is now offline
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: CPU 13 is now offline
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: CPU 14 is now offline
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: CPU 15 is now offline
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ACPI: PM: Low-level resume complete
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ACPI: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: LVT offset 0 assigned for vector 0x400
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: x86: Booting SMP configuration:
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C002: Found 2 idle states
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: CPU1 is up
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C004: Found 2 idle states
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: CPU2 is up
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C006: Found 2 idle states
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: CPU3 is up
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x8
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C008: Found 2 idle states
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: CPU4 is up
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0xa
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00A: Found 2 idle states
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: CPU5 is up
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0xc
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00C: Found 2 idle states
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: CPU6 is up
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0xe
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00E: Found 2 idle states
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: CPU7 is up
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 8 APIC 0x1
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C001: Found 2 idle states
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: Spectre V2 : Update user space SMT mitigation: STIBP always-on
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: CPU8 is up
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 9 APIC 0x3
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C003: Found 2 idle states
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: CPU9 is up
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 10 APIC 0x5
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C005: Found 2 idle states
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: CPU10 is up
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 11 APIC 0x7
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C007: Found 2 idle states
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: CPU11 is up
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 12 APIC 0x9
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C009: Found 2 idle states
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: CPU12 is up
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 13 APIC 0xb
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00B: Found 2 idle states
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: CPU13 is up
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 14 APIC 0xd
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00D: Found 2 idle states
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: CPU14 is up
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 15 APIC 0xf
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00F: Found 2 idle states
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: CPU15 is up
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S3
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: xHC error in resume, USBSTS 0x401, Reinit
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: usb usb1: root hub lost power or was reset
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: nvme nvme1: Shutdown timeout set to 8 seconds
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: nvme nvme0: Shutdown timeout set to 8 seconds
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: nvme nvme0: 32/0/0 default/read/poll queues
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: nvme nvme1: 32/0/0 default/read/poll queues
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 330)
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 330)
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 330)
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: usb 1-5: reset low-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: usb 1-3: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ata5: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 0)
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: usb 1-6: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: OOM killer enabled.
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: Restarting tasks ... done.
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: random: crng reseeded on system resumption
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER kernel: PM: suspend exit
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER systemd-resolved[1012]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1700022982.984:333): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.keepassxc.keepassxc" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00>
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1700022982.984:334): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.keepassxc.keepassxc" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00>
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1700022982.984:335): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.keepassxc.keepassxc" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00>
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1700022982.984:336): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.keepassxc.keepassxc" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00>
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1700022982.984:337): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.keepassxc.keepassxc" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00>
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1700022982.984:338): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.keepassxc.keepassxc" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00>
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER audit[6398]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.keepassxc.keepassxc" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-5/busnum" pid=6398 comm=">
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER audit[6398]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.keepassxc.keepassxc" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-3/busnum" pid=6398 comm=">
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER audit[6398]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.keepassxc.keepassxc" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-5/busnum" pid=6398 comm=">
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER audit[6398]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.keepassxc.keepassxc" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-3/busnum" pid=6398 comm=">
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER audit[6398]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.keepassxc.keepassxc" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-6/busnum" pid=6398 comm=">
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER audit[6398]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.keepassxc.keepassxc" name="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-6/busnum" pid=6398 comm=">
Nov 14 23:36:22 COMPUTER systemd-sleep[21845]: System returned from sleep state.
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER systemd-sleep[21961]: /dev/sda:
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER systemd-sleep[21961]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER systemd-sleep[21961]:  APM_level        = 254
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER systemd[1]: Starting Message of the Day...
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER systemd[1]: Starting Daily man-db regeneration...
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER systemd[1]: motd-news.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER systemd[1]: Finished Message of the Day.
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER systemd[1]: man-db.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER systemd[1]: Finished Daily man-db regeneration.
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER systemd[1]: Finished System Suspend.
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Consumed 1.142s CPU time.
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:69
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal DisplayPort
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 2670.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system resume actions...
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER suspend[22019]: nvidia-resume.service
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER logger[22019]: <13>Nov 14 23:36:23 suspend: nvidia-resume.service
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER systemd[1]: nvidia-resume.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system resume actions.
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): MONITOR (DFP-3): connected
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): MONITOR (DFP-3): Internal TMDS
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): MONITOR (DFP-3): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal DisplayPort
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 2670.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Nov 14 23:36:23 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): MONITOR2 (DFP-5): connected
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): MONITOR2 (DFP-5): Internal TMDS
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): MONITOR2 (DFP-5): 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "HDMI-1: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +1920+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}, DP-3: nvidia-auto-select @1>
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER systemd-logind[1205]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER audit[1154]: USER_AVC pid=1154 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface=>
                                    exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER ModemManager[1242]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is resuming
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER NetworkManager[1347]: <info>  [1700022984.1279] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER NetworkManager[1347]: <info>  [1700022984.1280] device (enp5s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1700022984.124:339): pid=1154 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/>
                               exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER kernel: rfkill: input handler disabled
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER kernel: Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-0-500:00: attached PHY driver (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-0-500:00, irq=MAC)
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER acpid[1142]: client 2495[1000:1000] has disconnected
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER acpid[1142]: client connected from 2495[1000:1000]
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER acpid[1142]: 1 client rule loaded
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) event5  - Razer Razer DeathAdder V2: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) event5  - Razer Razer DeathAdder V2: device is a pointer
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:68
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) event4  - Logitech USB Keyboard System Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) event4  - Logitech USB Keyboard System Control: device is a keyboard
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:65
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:67
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) event3  - Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) event3  - Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control: device is a keyboard
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:72
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) event8  - Razer Razer DeathAdder V2: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) event8  - Razer Razer DeathAdder V2: device is a keyboard
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:64
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) event0  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) event0  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:70
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) event6  - Razer Razer DeathAdder V2 Keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) event6  - Razer Razer DeathAdder V2 Keyboard: device is a keyboard
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:66
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) event2  - Logitech USB Keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (II) event2  - Logitech USB Keyboard: device is a keyboard
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER NetworkManager[1347]: <info>  [1700022984.3595] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER kernel: r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Down
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): MONITOR (DFP-3): connected
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): MONITOR (DFP-3): Internal TMDS
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): MONITOR (DFP-3): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): MONITOR (DFP-3): connected
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): MONITOR (DFP-3): Internal TMDS
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): MONITOR (DFP-3): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Nov 14 23:36:24 COMPUTER /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2495]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Nov 14 23:36:26 COMPUTER ModemManager[1242]: <info>  [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.2/0000:03:09.0/0000:05:00.0': not supported by any plugin
Nov 14 23:36:27 COMPUTER dbus-daemon[1154]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' unit='fprintd.service' requested by ':1.107' (uid=1000 pid=2628 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label>
Nov 14 23:36:27 COMPUTER systemd[1]: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
Nov 14 23:36:27 COMPUTER dbus-daemon[1154]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Nov 14 23:36:27 COMPUTER systemd[1]: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
Nov 14 23:36:27 COMPUTER gnome-shell[2628]: JS ERROR: Failed to initialize fprintd service: Gio.IOErrorEnum: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available
                                         asyncCallback@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:114:23
Nov 14 23:36:27 COMPUTER kernel: r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
Nov 14 23:36:27 COMPUTER kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp5s0: link becomes ready
...
```

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: @waltinator what's wrong with my question?

Comment: Lack of actionsble details, surfeit of unless information, refereence to some other Question (did you type everything correctly? ). I repeat  read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Stop closing my questions, you guys are annoying. My question was detailed, and the problem I was trying to solve was clear.

Comment: check out https://askubuntu.com/questions/1468300/suspend-problem-with-ubuntu-22-04/1493519#1493519

writing this here so you get the notification about it, there's a bug with B550 motherboards and SSD power stuff, workaround included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So without changing any more software, or software configurations, I got a new motherboard, a `MSI B550M-PRO-VDH WIFI`, swapped out my `Gigabyte 550 Gaming V2 rev 1.3`, and now sleep/suspend works!

Answer (score 0):

First step is to put a pin in the timestream with

```
date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' >pin.tmp
```

Then, do your suspend thing. When your system is usable again,

```
sudo journalctl  --since="$(cat pin.tmp)"
```

This will show you all the log messages since you set `pin.tmp`.

Comment: Thank you for this debugging tip, I have provided the log dump in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Check your BIOS is current. If it isn't, update it.

The current version looks to be F17c:

https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B550-GAMING-X-V2-rev-10-11-12/support#support-dl-bios

Comment: Hi Liam, thank you for the suggestion, I have the latest BIOS update for rev 1.3 installed.