Try and Install 24.04 won't on an msi b550 a pro
Selected Try and Install (ubuntu 24.04 desktop), and the usb flashes for a few seconds and stops on the msi b550 a pro. The screen remains blank. Pulled the ssd from the msi, installed it on another machine and installed ubuntu 24.04 with the same usb that failed to install on the msi machine. Booted up, no issues. Pulled the ssd from the machine the OS was installed on and reinstalled it in the msi box. Booting gets to the Ubuntu prompt. Hit return and nothing happens. Reinstalled the ssd in the box the OS was installed on and it boots fine.
Bios was upgraded to latest on the msi. Security was disabled. Tried configuring CSM and UEFI with same results. Bios sees 32g memory, cpu, usb pendisk and ssd drive.
Config is msi b550 a pro motherboard latest bios, 32g mem corsair (4x8g), ryzen 7 5700G amd cpu, kingston 240g ssd, and trying to get ubuntu 24.04 installed on the ssd.
Latest BIOS is from https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/B550M-A-PRO/support#bios , 7C96v2G1(Beta version).
Any suggestions for making the board recognize either the usb for Try and Install or the ssd to boot the os? What happens in the startup process 3-5 seconds after the boot to the os starts?
Continuing ... In other attempts at the grub prompt, Try and install, I edited the boot commands and removed the splash. In still another attempt, I installed the ubuntu 24.04 mini OS and booted with that. In both cases, diagnostics fly by and within about 1 sec, install stops; the diagnostics stop. Last two lines are USB hub found and 2 ports detected. The only thing left to do is turn off the machine.
Speculation: The ssd has Ubuntu 24.04 installed on it from another machine (not an msi motherboard). When booting on the msi board with the ssd, it's as if the msi boot doesn't know where to find the starting spot on the ssd to boot the os. Same seems to be true for the live usb and the Try and Install grub interface. Did the MSI bios change where to find the start of the OS boot? Did Ubuntu change where the MSI bios can no longer find the start of the OS boot?

You mention the release (24.04) but don't say which product (Server? Desktop? or flavor) as they use different installers.  FYI:  You shouldn't need to disable security IF you wrote the ISO correctly to your installation media (ie. used documented methods & didn't reformat it via options in ISO writing software)   On the machine where it worked, did you verify the ISO checks having completed?  (it's what I'd do to ensure media was written correctly; then you can investigate hardware issues having ruled media issues mostly out)

This question is similar to: Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. The Ubuntu minimal USB has a text-only interface that may enable you to get around the difficulty you are having with using the Ubuntu installer GUI version.

Even if not Asus, may be same: Asus Rog Strix B550 Disable IOMMU
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265397/unable-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-lts-via-live-usb-ryzen-5-3600?noredirect=1#comment2141726_1265397  After install: Gigabyte B550M Sleep issue
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1468300/suspend-problem-with-ubuntu-22-04
